# image tag only returning user avatar on homepage not on other pages

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5

1. I have a nav bar a home page and a page to post a question
2. user avatar is showing on home page not on post a question page below is my nav bar

   ```
   <a style="position:relative; padding-left:50px;">
       <img src="uploads/avatars/{{ $currentUser->avatar }}" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; border-radius:50%">
   Welcome {{ $currentUser->name }} </a>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a absolute path: `<img src="/uploads/avatars/...`

Notice the '/' at the beginning of the path.

Comment: What do you mean by beginning. where exactly

Comment: At the beginning of the source path, notice the / before the rest of the path. Otherwise the browser will append the path to your current page's path and look for the image there.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

- Home page: *demo.com/*
- Any page:  *demo.com/any-page/*

---

**Case 1:**

```
<img src="uploads/avatars/{{ $currentUser->avatar }}"
```

- Home page: Url image is *demo.com/uploads/avatars/...*
- Any page: Url image is *demo.com/any-page/uploads/avatars/...* => **Url
  image wrong**

---

**Case 2:**

```
<img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $currentUser->avatar }}"
```

- Home page: Url image is *demo.com/uploads/avatars/....*
- Any page: Url image is *demo.com/uploads/avatars/....* => **Url image correct**